# How to use the "with" statement inside an eex template in elixir phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to run the following code:

```
<%= with [%{time: time}| _rest] <- day_data do %>
  <p><%= Timex.lformat!(time, "{WDshort}", Gettext.get_locale()) %></p>
<% end %>
```

But that raises `(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %{} of type Map.`

Then I tried something super simple:

```
<%= with :foo <- :bar do %>
  <p><%= "eex shouldn't print this" %></p>
<% end %>
```

And that rendered me "`bar`" in the template. What? The? actual? bar?

I also tried it without the equal sign, but that didn't include the code in the template.

```
<% with number <- 1 do %>
  <p><%= "eex does not print this #{number}" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Can I even use the with statement in eex templates? Or do I have to go with:

```
<%= if match?([%{time: time}| _rest], day_data) do %>
  <% [%{time: time}| _rest] = day_data %>
  <p><%= Timex.lformat!(time, "{WDshort}", Gettext.get_locale()) %></p>
<% end %>
```

By the way I cannot believe no one has asked this before. I tried to search for an answer. Sorry if it turns out to be a duplicate.

**EDIT after the first answer:**
I also tried (syntax error before: '->'):

```
<%= with [%{time: time}| _rest] <- day_data do %>
  <p><%= Timex.lformat!(time, "{WDshort}", Gettext.get_locale()) %></p>
<% else %>
  <%= _err -> nil %>
<% end %>
```

No clause (expected -> clauses for :else in "with")

```
<%= with [%{time: time}| _rest] <- day_data do %>
  <p><%= Timex.lformat!(time, "{WDshort}", Gettext.get_locale()) %></p>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

And various possible ways to use or not use the equal sign. Also exchanged the `nil` with an empty string just to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1) returns the RHO immediately if there is no match.

That said, either you need to handle both possible cases with `else` or ensure that what’s returned is renderable (as in your case of `:foo <- :bar`.)

What happens, is `<%=` attempts to render not matched `day_data` and fails.

---

To introduce `else` one should use the following syntax

```elixir
<%= with foo <- 42 do %>
  <p><%= MATCH: #{foo} %></p>
<% else _ -> %>
  <p><%= NO MATCH %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Still.. Somehow I'm not overcoming syntax errors for the else clause. I tried various combinations of `<% else %>  <%= _err -> nil %>`. It doesn't like the `->`.

The second suggestion I tried (see question). It does not print anything even if the match is successful.

Comment: I have updated the answer with `else`.